# Getting the hash of an application

Tags: android

In my Android application I want to create a list of all android applications on an Android device including the hash of the base apk file. Making the list is possible with the packagemanager class, but I couldn't find the option to get the hash from the base apk.

What I have found is that it is possible to get the hash of application with the securitylog class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/SecurityLog#TAG_APP_PROCESS_START). The problem with this is you only get the hash when the user starts an application. your application also must be the device owner, that is not the biggest issue but preferably without these rights.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the hash from all the installed base apk's with or without being the device owner.

Comment: You can retrieve the full path of the APK using the PackageManager API. You can then attempt to actually read the APK from the filesystem and compute the hash using whatever algorithm you need.

Comment: @AleksG Thanks for your comment. I will try this soon!